How can I evaluate string-formatted column conditions against an unregistered record?
DO $$
DECLARE
    rec RECORD;
    outcome BOOLEAN;
    rule TEXT;
BEGIN
    -- Assume the record references a single row that contains the columns under test in the rule
    rule := 'columnA > 30 OR columnB < 50';
END;
$$
 LANGUAGE plpgsql;

Here is a concise block with an example of the rule I would like to evaluate against the record. I imagine I need to EXECUTE a dynamic SQL statement.
I want to determine the type of the record dynamically at runtime as I have easy access to another string with the table name. I envisioned casting to table_name%ROWTYPE. As far as I can understand, I cannot dynamically cast a RECORD to a composite type at runtime.
I then thought of using row_to_json(rec) but then would need to evaluate the rule against this JSON object. I am not familiar with how to do this in PL/pgSQL.
I am fetching from a CURSOR into a RECORD because I want an iterator I can pass to different functions that does not have the overhead of a TEMPORARY TABLE. I am fairly new to PL/pgSQL, I would say only a few thousand LOC into the language so I am still learning how to work with its control structures. I am considering I may need to back up a bit and choose different control and/or data structures for the problem. How would you approach this problem?


As far as I can understand, I cannot dynamically cast a RECORD to a composite type at runtime.

We cannot cast record to a well-defined row type, simply because no cast has been defined. Not possible for an anonymous input type. But everything can be cast to text via basic I/O functions, even record. So use text as stepping stone.
We still need dynamic SQL to convert the string in rule to SQL code - which is always open to SQL injection. Make sure not to take input from untrusted sources!
You implied that rec is based on an actual table type. We can work with that (or any matching registered row type for that matter). Say:
CREATE TABLE t1 (column_a int, column_b int, js jsonb);

Then:
DO
$do$
DECLARE
   _rec  record := (SELECT t FROM (SELECT 31, 10, '{"foo":"bar"}') t(column_x, column_y, bar));  -- !
   _rule text := 'column_a > 30 OR column_b < 50';
   _ct   int;
BEGIN
   EXECUTE 'SELECT FROM (SELECT ($1::text::t1).*) t WHERE ' || _rule  -- !
   USING _rec;

   GET DIAGNOSTICS _ct = ROW_COUNT;

   IF _ct = 0 THEN  -- rec violates rule
     -- do something?
   END IF;

   RAISE NOTICE 'Rule passed: %', _ct;  -- debug
END
$do$

fiddle
Note that column names of the record are just noise; they are lost in the cast. Only column names of the registered table (t1) are visible after the cast. So be sure that the row type fits!
Related:

Trigger function using current row and current table name as variables
Dynamic access to record column in plpgsql function


Chances are, there is a simpler approach. I have rarely encountered the need to use an explicit cursor in PL/pgSQL. Typically an attempt to apply patterns from other RDBMS.
